# byte array to MimeMultipart

Tags: java, encoding, hex, mime

I'm writing a type of encoder/decoder for MimiMultipart.
Encoder: MimiMultipart -> HexString
Decoder: HexString -> MimiMultipart

This method creates MimeMultipart for later encoding:

```
private MimeMultipart compose_mail(String to, String body) throws Exception{
    Document d = XMLConnector.get("body.html");
    String html_body = d.html();

    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

    // Body part
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setContent(html_body, "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // Image part
    File img_file = new File("img/logo.png");

    MimeBodyPart messageImgPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageImgPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    messageImgPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<logo>");
    messageImgPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
    messageImgPart.setFileName("logo inline image");
    messageImgPart.attachFile(img_file);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageImgPart);

    return MimeMultipart;
}
```

This method encodes MimeMultipart to HexString: 
(It also attaches content type with boundary.)

```
public String encode(MimeMultipart body) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    body.writeTo(baos);
    String hex_body = Hex.encodeHexString(baos.toByteArray());
    hex_body += ";" + body.getContentType();
    return hex_body;
}
```

The last method has to decode the string:

```
public MimeMultipart decode(String encoded_body) throws Exceptions {
    MimeMultipart body = null;
    String[] parts = encoded_body.split(";", 2); 
    byte[] body_b = Hex.decodeHex(parts[0].toCharArray());
    ByteArrayDataSource bads = new ByteArrayDataSource(body_b, parts[1]);
    body = new MimeMultipart(bads);
    return body;  
}
```

Some checks I did:
1) I sent original MimeMultipart:

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
msg.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
Transport.send(msg);
```

I got the mail as needed (html visible as html, image as image).
When I sent encoded->decoded mail same way, I got source html instead rendered one, and image seems broken.
2) I checked decoded MimeMultipart and saw 0 parts.

What may be wrong here?

UPDATE:
About 2: MimeMultipart contains 0 parts, because parsing from stream is done only on demand, ie during getParts() call.

Comment: What do you mean by "encoded->decoded mail"? Do you mean you are encoding it, then immediately decoding it again, then sending it? That doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: It's only to make it simple to you.  
The real flow is:  
Encode->(Send by mail/via db to other location)->Decode on another comp

Comment: I don't understand. HTML is just HTML. There is no such thing as "source HTML" or "rendered HTML", there are only two ways of viewing HTML - as plain text, or as a web page. How are you viewing the HTML after decoding it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine Source html is what you write in notepad, rendered one is what you see in rendering engine (browser, mail client etc)

Comment: What I meant is that rendered page that I see in mail client is ok, but after encoding+decoding I see html instead rendered page.